# How to break to the second foreachloop c#

Tags: c#

Guys How Can I break to the second loop of this conditions?

I Have to get the combitations of values
The COMBINATION MIGHT have 6 values.
but some of the values are null or ""
What I want to do is, get all the possibles combinations.
If the values is null or "" I want to break to the second loop, because the first condition that set the rest of the combinations, if it's not 
 I Want to continue ultil its finish all the possibles combinations.
In this scneario my code it's comming back to the last loop.
Any ideas?

```
foreach (var item in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria1").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
{
    foreach (var item2 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria2").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
    {
        foreach (var item3 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria3").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
        {
            foreach (var item4 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria4").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
            {
                foreach (var item5 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria5").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value == "").ToList())
                {
                    foreach (var item6 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria6").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think recursion will be your best friend here.

Comment: maybe ´goto´ is the key what you need

Comment: With your code you have to say `performance` good bye.

Comment: @RandRandom That's simply the nature of combinatorics.  The size of the output alone scales horribly with input size, regardless of how well you implement it.  Thus such problems simply require small input sizes.  Nothing else to be done if those are your requirements.  Obviously if that's not actually an inherent requirement, then you should avoid performing combinatorics like this at all costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the second loop, create a var that stores whether you found a null:

```
//at beginning of second loop
bool foundNull = false;
```

When you check and find a null, set this var:

```
//anywhere you need to check if a value is null
if (isSomeValueNull(someValue))
{
    foundNull = true;
    break;
}
```

In every loop (except the second and first, of course), after the inner loop, check for this:

```
//after every inner loop
if (foundNull == true)
    break;
```

---

```
foreach (var item in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria1").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
{
    foreach (var item2 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria2").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
    {
        bool foundNull = false;

        foreach (var item3 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria3").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
        {
            foreach (var item4 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria4").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
            {
                foreach (var item5 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria5").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value == "").ToList())
                {
                    foreach (var item6 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria6").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())
                    {
                        if (isSomeValueNull(someValue))
                        {
                            foundNull = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (foundNull == true)
                        break;
                }
                if (foundNull == true)
                    break;
            }
            if (foundNull == true)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried, This should work but when I use break, the code comes back to the previous loop no to the second 

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm saying you must put that "after every inner loop" until the second

Comment: I tried this way but it gets me less combinations, the first code gives me 575 combinations, this way I Recieve just 339 combinations, I can't understand why, it should work..

Comment: I'm check the variable every inner loop and if it's null I Hit the break, but somehow it breaks to the previous loop no to the second loop

Comment: Maybe i'm explain this the wrong way let's try again, 
Inside the foreach condition                 
    foreach (var item6 in result.ComboValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nameId == "Categoria6").selectValueText.Where(x => x.value != "").ToList())

the code go to previous loop because it dind't find any value diffrent of "" so it come backs to the previous loop no to the second loop. So my problem it's exclaty this, inside the foreach condition if doens't contains any values diffent thant "" it come back to the previous loop and I need to go to the second loop.

Comment: Yes, my answer deals with this problem.